# Replace node with innerhtml

Tags: javascript, html, dom

With JavaScript I want to remove a specific DOM node and replace it with the innerHTML. For example I want to change

```
<div>
...
   <div id="t1">
        this is <b> the text </b> I want to remain.
   </div>
...
</div>
```

To

```
<div>
...
    this is <b> the text </b> I want to remain.
...
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
var oldElem = document.getElementById('t1');
oldElem.innerHTML = 'this is <b> the text </b> I want to remain.';
var parentElem = oldElem.parentNode;
var innerElem;

while (innerElem = oldElem.firstChild)
{
  // insert all our children before ourselves.
  parentElem.insertBefore(innerElem, oldElem);
}
parentElem.removeChild(oldElem);
```

There is a demo [here](http://jsbin.com/oqobe).

This is effectively the same thing as [`.replaceWith()`](http://api.jquery.com/replaceWith) from jQuery:

```
$("#t1").replaceWith('this is <b> the text </b> I want to remain.');
```

Answer (score 2):

`var t1 = document.getElementById("t1");
t1.outerHTML = "this is <b> the text </b> I want to remain.";`

http://youmightnotneedjquery.com/#replace_from_html

Answer (score 1):

If you are using [jQuery](http://jquery.com/), you can try

```
var inner = j$("#t1").html()
$('#t1').replaceWith(inner);
```

Comment: What if I have the retrieved the node by tag name. For example: 

var celem=document.getElementsByTagName("span");

I want to do this on all node elements in celem.

Answer (score 1):

This works:

```
var t1 = document.getElementById("t1");
t1.parentNode.innerHTML = t1.innerHTML;
```

**Edit:**

Please note that if the parent of t1 has any other children, the above will remove all those children too. The following fixes this problem:

```
var t1 = document.getElementById("t1");
var children = t1.childNodes;
for (var i = 0; i < children.length; i++) {
    t1.parentNode.insertBefore(children[i].cloneNode(true), t1);
}
t1.parentNode.removeChild(t1);
```

Comment: The weakness of this solution is that the parent of t1 (i.e. t0 in your example) might have various other nodes inside. This solution removes those nodes.

Comment: Why clone the node before you move it into it's parent? Why not just move it?  You're going to be removing all the originals anyway...

Answer (score 1):

It's very easy actually:

```
let span = document.getElementById('id');
span.outerHTML = span.innerHTML;
```

Answer (score 0):

I just modified the HTML Like this.

```
<div>
<div id="t0">
<div id="t1">
        this is <b> the text </b> I want to remain.
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

And you do something like

```
document.getElementById("t0").innerHTML = "this is <b> the text </b> I want to remain.";
```

Hope it works

Comment: The weakness of this solution is that the parent of t1 (i.e. t0 in your example) might have various other nodes inside. This solution removes those nodes.

Answer (score 0):

you might want to consider using [jquery](http://jquery.com/) if that's possible.
it would make your life way way wayyyyyyyy easier.

once you have jquery, you can easily do this via

```
$("#t1").html("this is <b> the text </b> I want to remain.");
```

and if you find it a hassle to learn, you can always start by learning the jquery selectors. 
you wouldn't know why you haven't been using it all this while :)

sorry if this is not what you want exactly..

~jquery addict

### Updated:

To show what html text to put inside.

Comment: What should I put in place of "put your values here"? Must it be "this is <b> the text </b> I want to remain."?

Comment: yup, please check the updated code above. because the html takes html codes.

Answer (score 0):

This is similar to the other answers but more functional.

```js
go.onclick = () => {
  [...t1.childNodes].forEach(e => {
    t1.parentElement.insertBefore(e, t1);
  });
  t1.remove();
  go.disabled = true;
}
```

```css
#t1 {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div>
   <div>BEFORE</div>
   <div id="t1">
        this is <b> the text </b> I want to remain.
   </div>
   <div>AFTER</div>
   <button id="go">GO</button>
</div>
```